# Unexpected output when using q.js

Tags: javascript, exception, q

I have the following code:

```
        var p1 = Q($.ajax({
            url: "/api/test1"
        }));

        p1.then(function () {
            console.log("success1");
        });

        p1.then(function () {
            throw "some error";
            console.log("success2");
        });

        p1.then(function () {
            console.log("success3");
        });

        p1.catch(function () {
            console.log("failure1");
        });
        p1.catch(function () {
            console.log("failure2");
        });

        p1.finally(function () {
            console.log("finally1");
        });
        p1.finally(function () {
            console.log("finally2");
        });
```

I am expecting the following output assuming that I get some data back from api/test1 - "success1, failure1, failure2, finally1, finally2"

What I actually get is 
"success1, success3, finally1, finally3"

"Success3" is puzzling me - why is the code propagating to the 2nd then when an exception occurred?

How can I write this so that I can catch any exceptions that might occur in the then part(s)?

Ta

Answer (score 0):

The reason "Success3" is showing is because your promises are not chained.
Basically the "then" calls (as well as the "catch" and "finally" for that matter) are interdependent of each other.  If you think of it as a tree structure, they are all children of the `p1` promise.  If you want them to be dependent, they would be to have a child, grandchild, great-grandchild, etc relationship. If you want to chain them together, you can do something like:

```
    var p1 = Q($.ajax({
        url: "/api/test1"
    }));

    p1.then(function () {
        console.log("success1");
    }).then(function() {
        throw "some error";
        console.log("success2");
    }).catch(function () {
        console.log("failure");
    });
```

Which is basically implicitly returning the promise after each function runs.  The subsequent "then" (or catch/finally) is applied to that (implicit) return value.